# How to get correct values without checking the datatype of each column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am writing lots of queries to use in reports and statistics,
often I need average values, so I use `avg(column)` but that has a problem

look at this example

```
declare @table table (value int)
insert into @table values (2), (3)

select avg(t.value),
       avg(convert(decimal(16,2), t.value)),
       avg(t.value/1.0)
from   @table t
```

the result will be

```
2     2.5     2.5
```

The first value `2` is wrong. The average of 2 and 3 is not 2, but 2.5

Now I know this is because column `Value` is of type `int` and because of this the result is also returned in an int.

But that just is not practical. I never have any use for that, I always need to convert. I cannot think of any case where I want the avg of 2 and 3 to be 2.

So what is my problem,
I have many queries to write on lots of tables and columns, if I need to check for each column what the datatype is and write convert where needed, that not only takes a lot of time, but is is very dangerous, it is so easy to forget one which will introduce a bug in the report.
Is there a way to write this without having to convert first ?

Do I have to always write `value/1.0` no matter what the datatype is ?

This is something that is so easy to forget, mistakes are made so fast.
Also, can this affect performance if I always have to divide all values before calling a function ?

What is the best way of doing this ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're after. Something like `t.value/1.0` will work in cases where `t.value` is a numeric type (which is also when it would make sense to sum it). The result may not have the desired precision, in which case you'd still need an explicit cast. There is no switch, option or T-SQL trick that could make operations on an `INT` yield a `DECIMAL` without conversion. Consider using views on your base data instead that proactively convert the base data to `DECIMAL` before you aggregate (assuming changing the type in the tables is not an option, of course).

Comment: I think `avg(t.value/1.0)` covers all number formats. Following up this question.

Comment: As for performance considerations, the conversion to `DECIMAL` isn't an issue; any perf hit will instead come from doing aggregations on `DECIMAL`, which is inherently slower than doing them on `INT` or `FLOAT`. This, however, should not be a concern until after the data is actually correct.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Changing the DataTypes in the tables is not an option, I want to have all columns with the exact and correct datatype, so if the values never have decimals I will make it int or bigint.

Comment: Then views are your best option, if you really don't want to change your aggregates. With some effort these can be generated automatically based on the base tables, though doing that in T-SQL is quite clunky (due to the need for dynamic SQL).